# How to get the WMS link from geoportal

Tags: qgis, python, wms, tiles, geoportal

I have the address of Israel geoportal and I want to get the WMS link of these data. Actually I just need the satellite imagery data and I want to load it to the QGIS as a reference map. So the question could also be "How to add the satellite imagery from Israel geoportal into the QGIS"? Usually these geoportals have a wms server links which could be easily added to the QGIS.
This is the geoportal:
https://www.govmap.gov.il/?c=176744.1,575757.91&z=10&b=1&sb=11

Comment: The portal proxies tile request via their webservers - for a reason (security, proprietary data etc.). If there's no public endpoint (WMS etc.), it seems contacting their support is your only (legal) option.

Comment: Tile request are perhaps rewritten with javascript with this code https://map.govmap.gov.il/js_api_3/esri/layers/WebTiledLayer.js?3.2.0

Comment: @user30184 Is there a way to add this to QGIS, ArcGIS or Global Mapper as layer?

Answer (score 1):

This is the public WMS URL for "govMap Israel":
https://open.govmap.gov.il/geoserver/opendata/wms?

However, there are only few layers which are available from that service, as listed in the screenshot from QGIS software:

[image: govMap Israel WMS Layers]